# C# RegEx get attributes from CREATE TABLE

Tags: c#, sql, regex

I need a `RegEx` to get name of table, keys and every attribute from `CREATE TABLE` statement... for example:
Here I create this table, and i need to get all attributes

```
​CREATE
​  TABLE KATEGORIE
​  (
​    id INTEGER NOT NULL ,
​    nazev NVARCHAR (20) NOT NULL ,
​    cena INTEGER NOT NULL ,
​    CONSTRAINT KATEGORIE_PK PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (id)
​WITH
​  (
​    ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON ,
​    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON
​  )
​  ON "default"
​  )
​  ON "default"
​GO
```

So far I have this: `\s*CREATE\s*TABLE\s*(.*)\s*\(\s*(.*\s*) ;` but this wont work, because there is always different number of attributes, I need to get all of them and end when word `"WITH"` or `')'` shows up. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'd suggest finding a SQL parser instead.  Check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.sqlparser.parser.parser(v=sql.120).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, thanks for help. I edited regex, for taking anything before ',' and i iterate through it, then i get last line.